# Endpoint design for single and bulk requests

Tags: design, architecture, python, rest

I'm working on a project in Python and want to get it hosted for others to use, the internal recommendation has been to host it on AzureML (it is a non-machine learning model, but follows the same practices of having a model and scoring script).

A Python script on a single request would return the result in 0.1seconds.

A Python script on 100k requests would run them vectorised in a pandas DataFrame in 10seconds (example number, but not far off the real time).

An AzureML real-time endpoint would return a single request in 0.1seconds.

An AzureML batch endpoint on 100k requests would run 100 instances of batches of size 1000, and return all results in 100seconds (1000 * 0.1), alongside a cold-start time of ~5minutes, and some extra latency of about 10seconds.

The script **needs** to be used in both a single-request real-time scenario, as well as the bulk scenario, regularly. The batch endpoint taking ~6minutes is too long but I'm led to believe it's the best option and best practice for this scenario.

My question is whether AzureML is the best place for this kind of endpoint, and what other options are out there (we are fairly stuck with being in the Azure ecosystem, but other options are welcome).

I don't have much experience with endpoints, but it seems more logical to host a real-time endpoint that can accept either single-request input or multi-request input, with the Python script dealing with data wrangling/outputs.

Comment: The actual question expressed in the second-to-last paragraph is asking for an opinion (since there is no objective "best" solution) and a list of alternatives. Both kinds of question are off-topic on Software Engineering SE, I'm afraid. With the info given nobody can even give good advice, I think your 10 seconds for 100k requests in Python looks somewhat unbelievable compared to your times cited for AzureML. Did you actually measure these times?

Comment: These are measured times, yes. The comparison being a single request of 100k into Python (vectorised calculations), versus a batch request of 100k into AzureML, which essentially runs a for-loop over single requests in parallel.
I wasn't sure of the best place to ask this kind of question, do you know of a better place?